# What sort of maths is represented on this Hungarian stamp issued in 2000?

Tags: math-history

I collect stamps on selected topics in physics and maths. Does anyone recognise the type of mathematics represented top left on this Hungarian stamp sheet issued in 2000?

[image]

It celebrates the work of Dénes Gábor on holography and a two channel hologram is featured (his portrait in one direction, holography optics ray diagram in another). The theory I’ve found so far on holography doesn’t look to be associated with the maths given, though.

57 Hungarian mathematicians are also named along this stamp's borders:

[image]

However, the names are only visible under UV light. Maybe the mathematics associated with one of these mathematicians is shown. Thanks.

Comment: Not unlikely familiar of the famous actress, also Hungarian, Zsa Zsa Gabor, Denis Gabor was a physicist (I read on Google) awarded the Nobel Prize. And we all know that Physics can not do without mathematics. In addition, holograms are a technological marvel whose principles are undoubtedly mathematical in terms of physical optics,

Comment: The first line deals undoubtly with a form of duality in convex analysis, but I cannot say more, even less regarding a hungarian connection...

Comment: The third line from top is the König theorem in set theory of cardinal numbers.

Comment: The first line looks like a variant of Farkas lemma. It is truncated though, should be $+\lambda_m g_m$ instead of $+\lambda$ at the end. Farkas was [Hungarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyula_Farkas_(natural_scientist)).

Comment: @A.Γ. good point, I could not make sense of it as written.

Comment: The second line is an iteration whose limit is a root of $x^m=a+x$.

Comment: @WillJagy But what is the second one? Looks like a nested radical. Maybe related to Bolyai expansion somehow?

Comment: Thank you for the insights which confirm that the equations are not related to holography theory but at least two to the mathematicians listed. The header for the names in Hungarian and also revealed with UV light is 'Outstanding Hungarian Mathematicians".

Magyar Posta have a page devoted to this stamp describing the many design elements. Different number systems are used in the elliptical orbits to give the millennium year.
[link](https://www.posta.hu/stamps/stamps/specialities/the_turn_of_the_millennium)